# Time latency for snakemake

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I have this rule:

```
rule Bam_coverage:
    input: "ALIGN/result/{case}_filter_dup.bam"
    output: "result/{case}.bw"
    params: genome=config['reference']['genome_fasta'],
            name=lambda wildcards, input: input[0][:-4]
    threads: 6
    log: "log/{case}.bamcoverage.report.txt"
    conda:
         "envs/deeptools.yaml"
    shell:
        """
         bamCoverage -b  {input}  -o {output} -of bigwig -bs 50 -p {threads}  &2> {log}
        """
```

When I launch snakemake the program runs, but snakemake gives me this error:

```
Error in job Bam_coverage while creating output file result/MB.neg.27ac_27ac.bw.

MissingOutputException in line 21 of /home/maurizio/Desktop/TEST_chip/rules/deeptools.rules:
Missing files after 60 seconds:
result/MB.neg.27ac_27ac.bw
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
```

However, the program is in background and after some time writes the file.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the commant into the background with the `&2>` at the end (bash interprets the `&` as the forking operator). What you mean is `> {log} 2>&1` (i.e., redirect stderr to stdout).